# Why do Python dict consuming more memory when stored with more than 550k keys

Tags: python

I use Python's dict type to store a data file with more than 550k keys, almost 29M. however, after reading the data file, the memory used is more than 70M which is unnormal.

So, how does this happen?

Below is the function to read the data file.

```
def _update_internal_metrics(self, signum, _):
    """Read the dumped metrics file"""
    logger.relayindex('reload dumped file begins')
    dumped_metrics_file_path = os.path.join(settings.DATA_DIR,
                                            settings.DUMPED_METRICS_FILE)
    epoch = int(time.time())
    try:
        new_metrics = {}
        with open(dumped_metrics_file_path) as dumped_metrics_file:
            for line in dumped_metrics_file:
                line = line.strip()
                new_metrics[line] = epoch
    except Exception:
        if not signum:
            self._reload_dumped_file()
        logger.relayindex("Dumped metrics file does not exist or can"
                          "not be read. No update")
    else:
        settings["metrics"] = new_metrics

    instrumentation.increment('dumped.Reload')
    logger.relayindex('reload dumped file ends')
```

Comment: What is `55w`? 55 thousand (55k), 55 million (55m)? How did you store the data in a file and load it again? Dictionaries use a hash table, and it depends on the insertion and deletion history how large a table is used. However, 29M vs 70M sounds excessive. How did you measure the memory footprint?

Comment: sorry for my poor english. It should be 550k keys. I see it with a `top` command.

Comment: It's not really excessive. There's the overhead for the object pointers, and with the 2x growth factor it's possible that after all the insertions the table is relatively sparse. It would be nice to know what kind of objects are stored, and what format the datafile has.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath , the key is string, and the value is a timestamp. you can check the source code in the question body. :)

Comment: @andy: wasn't there when I made the comment ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath , yes, i added it later. I just want to make sure that if Python dict can hold more than 550k keys with not so many memory.

Comment: Is this a 64bit system?

Comment: @Karoly , yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `top` isn't the right way to check it, as it will tell you the memory consumption of the whole process. You can use `getsizeof` from the `sys` module:

```
sys.getsizeof(new_metrics)
```

Second, there are some overhead associated both with strings and hash tables:

```
sys.getsizeof('')
```

On my system this is `24` bytes overhead, and the overhead is consistent regardless of the string size. With 550k keys that's about 13M overhead.

Python tries to keep the hash tables not too dense as that would kill the lookup time. AFAIK the `cpython` implementation uses a 2x growth factor, with 2^k table sizes. As your key size is just above a factor of two (`math.log(550000,2) # 19.06`), it's relatively sparse with `2 ** 20 = 1048576` slots. On your 64 bit system with 8 byte object pointers per string that's an additional 8M overhead. You also store integers, which weren't in the original file (another 8M), and each hash table slot also contains the stored hash value (another 8M). See the source of [PyDictEntry](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Include/dictobject.h#L50-58).

That's 66M total, and of course you need some space for the rest of your python app. It all looks fine to me.

Comment: i invoke the function `_update_internal_metrics` in question when a SIGUSR1 signal is sent to the program. However, after each invocation, the memory is increasing. It is not like a memory leak, however it does really increase the memory usage(with `top` command). And it sees like a memory leak and this makes me craze for a day. I can not find where the memory is leaked. I have checked with `sys.getsizeof` on `settings["metrics"]` after the assignment in `_update_internal_metrics`. It is the same and do not increase. However, i have found the `RES` in `top` command increase. This is crazy.

Comment: For the record: A 64-bit cpython dict filled with 29m worth of 52-char random strings has 25MiB for the dict alone (with 557k keys).

Comment: @andy: you have to post code which reproduces the problem.